# Kivy pyJnius access to system keys

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius

I try to make Python app for android using kivy and pyJnius where necessary to listen events from HW System Keys such as VolumeUp/down. I try to make function which catch key pressDown and return the keyID of the pressed key.
'''

```
from jnius import autoclass
event=autoclass(android.view.KeyEvent)
while True:
 code=event.getKeyCode()
 action=event.getAction()
 print(code, actions)
```

'''
but no one method from that class working, return 0 allways.
Unfortunately can not find any exemple for that, please advise or link for get keyID with kivy.

Comment: Do you not get these via kivy, if you bind to `Window.on_key_down`?

Comment: please write code string. As I read about kivy lib it work with screan keyboard, I shell chek if it work with system hw keys.

Comment: @inclement `Window.bind(on_key_down=self.key_handler)` does not call `def key_handler(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):` for volume buttons press or back button tap. (Android 11, sdk 27)

Comment: Hi Jack, had try to make window.bind as recomended it work with keyboard, on the android phone it can see event from backKey same as keyboards esc, but unfortunatly events from system keys volUp volDown  not available.